# Assigning an excel file to the script so I can run the code below

Tags: vba, excel

I have a similar scenario to the one below

```
Sub SliceNDice() 
Dim objRegex As Object 
Dim X 
Dim Y 
Dim lngRow As Long 
Dim lngCnt As Long 
Dim tempArr() As String 
Dim strArr 

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
objRegex.Pattern = "^\s+(.+?)$" 
'Define the range to be analysed
X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp)).Value2 
Redim Y(1 To 2, 1 To 1000) 
For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1) 
'Split each string by ","
   tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",") 
For Each strArr In tempArr 
      lngCnt = lngCnt + 1 
     'Add another 1000 records to resorted array every 1000 records
      If lngCnt Mod 1000 = 0 Then Redim Preserve Y(1 To 2, 1 To lngCnt + 1000) 
           Y(1, lngCnt) = X(lngRow, 1) 
           Y(2, lngCnt) = objRegex.Replace(strArr, "$1") 
     Next 
Next lngRow
'Dump the re-ordered range to columns C:D
[c1].Resize(lngCnt, 2).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Y) 

End Sub
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18MuV.png]

But in order to implement the code above -- I need to reference it to an excel file . How do I do that ? For instance , my file is stored in the location C:\SI .how do I reference it so that I can use the code above to work on that file. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Could you please format your post properly.

Comment: What do you mean by _reference it to an excel file_?  If you dump the code into a module within an Excel file it will reference whichever Excel file is active when the code runs.  `Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp))` always references the active sheet in the active workbook as you haven't specified a specific sheet/file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the workbook, store it as a variable and work against that variable.

```
Sub OpenWorkbookFileAndRunAgainstThat()
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\SI\workbook.xlsx")

With wb
    .Worksheets("yourSheet").Range("A1").value = "something" 'This is instead of Range in the sample above.
End with
End Sub
```